# Possible to determine what shell extensions are slowing down Windows?

Tags: windows-7, shell, troubleshooting, shell-extensions

Other than systematically disabling/enabling shell extensions, piece by piece --

Is there a way to measurably determine if/what shell extensions are bogging down the right-clicking of files/folders in Windows 7?

I'm wondering if there's a method or tool to determine such. I'm aware of the ShellExView/ShellMenuView, but they don't have any "diagnosing" ability.

I'm guessing there's an extension(s) that's doing some sort of overzealous scanning, like scanning the file itself or the surrounding directory(ies) or even the network. But combing through Task Manager doesn't net anything that sticks out from the bunch.